# RowNumber() and SUM() in one query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

is there some way who to get last record using rownumber() and SUM of one field (money in this case)?
I've tried to come up with a query like:

```
SELECT 
        [date]
        ,...
    FROM
        (
        SELECT
             CAST(t.timestamp AS DATE)              AS [date]
            ,.../some fields/
            ,row_number() over (partition by ca.logical_number order by t.timestamp DESC) as rownumber --last update(record) transaction
            --,amount_transferred = 
            --(
            --  SELECT
            --      ,SUM(t.money_value)     AS  amount_transferred
            --   FROM
            --      TO_Transaction t
            --  GROUP BY
            --      CAST(t.timestamp AS Date)
            --)

        ) AS t
    WHERE rownumber=1
```

What the query is supposed to do is to find current purse balance and all money transferred during a day.
Any help would be aprreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: It looks like you are missing a FROM section.  You have AS t and then reference it within the () inside of the AS t aliased section.  I would assume there are at least 2 tables you would like data from. The first is the table you want row numbers from and the second is the where you want the sum result from. Which table is which?

Comment: Actually no. I inappropriately deleted because the code length limitation in an question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you can also do `sum(field) over (...)`

```
select
  row_number() over (partition by ca.logical_number order by t.timestamp DESC) as rownumber,
  sum(amount_transfered) over (partition by ca.logical_number ) as total_amount_transfered
from ...
```

Comment: Thanks @Gordon - order by makes no sense in a sum.

Comment: My godness, it probably works! :-) Will mark as right answer when the time needed before expires.

Comment: @StanislavJirák shocking!

Comment: I'm new to SQL and after some time spent, I was going to split the procedure into 2 pieces.

Comment: I'm old to sql and the day i realised i could add an `over()` to any aggregate function was a good day!

Comment: Yes, it seems over() is quite handy. This is good day fro me!